# Rmarkdown rendering of tables for two-column latex output

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to get `Rmarkdown` to produce a table generated by the `pander_return` function from the `pander` package in a two-column latex environment. When I render to pdf there are strange newlines and line-breaks that appear in the final pdf file. When the output is rendered to html or to single-column pdf then there are not problems.

Here is a minimal example, that produces the strange behaviour.

````
---
title: test this
output: pdf_document
documentclass: report
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Part}
  - \newcommand{\fullline}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}
  - \newcommand{\bminione}{\begin{minipage}{0.75 \textwidth}}
  - \newcommand{\bminitwo}{\begin{minipage}{0.25 \textwidth}}
  - \newcommand{\emini}{\end{minipage}}
---

```{r echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE }
library(ggplot2)
```

# Variable list
## **charVar**

\bminione

----------------------------------
Feature                     Result
----------------------- ----------
Variable type               factor

Number of missing obs.  1 (6.67 %)

Number of unique values          4
----------------------------------

\emini
\bminitwo
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.width=4, fig.height=3, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE }
qplot(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor", na.action = structure(15L, class = "omit")),
    geom = "bar", xlab = "", main = "charVar")
```
\emini
````

The output looks like this

[image]

where there is an extra blank line inserted. This happens for some tables but not all.

If I look at the tex file produced by running

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
```

then I can see that table the generated tex file is a bloody mess. In particular the table is rendered as

```
\bminione

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lr@{}}
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.31\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Feature
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.13\columnwidth}\raggedleft\strut
Result
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Variable type
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.13\columnwidth}\raggedleft\strut
factor
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Number of missing obs.
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.13\columnwidth}\raggedleft\strut
1 (6.67 \%)
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Number of unique values
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.13\columnwidth}\raggedleft\strut
4
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\emini
```

which results in minipages within minipages. Not a happy situation.

[This link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1023) mentions that `longtable` is not compatible with 2-column LaTeX documents, and discusses various ways of redefining the `longtable` environment to potentially fix it but I was hoping that there would be a simpler way of converting the tables to something simpler that would render as intended. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think this issue was [fixed in `pander`](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/pull/254), can you please try the dev version installed from GitHub? There should be some extra whitespace in the markdown  table

Comment: That did indeed work. Thank you very much